# exclude dynamic number from rand in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to build an image based on a calculated encryption key. This is purely for me training myself to get better in PHP. The image should be something like the Telegram encryption. I currently have the code below to calculate the number of squares in each color. What I don't know, is how to go from here and fill up a table with these colored squares. I can generate coordinates using rand, but how do I exclude the squares that are already filled up?

**PHP**

```
//number of squares with a certain color
$white = rand (0, 50);
$lightblue = rand (0, 200);
$whiteblue = $white + $lightblue;
$darkblue = rand ($whiteblue, 750);
$total = '1024';
$mediumblue = $total - ($darkblue + $whiteblue);

$totalsquares = $white + $lightblue + $mediumblue + $darkblue;

//number of letters in white squares
$letters = rand(0, $white);
```

Comment: `'1024'` - ouch. don't. it's a number.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, that was stupid indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code a little bit to make it a little easier to manage.  Essentially, it adds the appropriate number of coloured squares to an array, then that array is shuffled.  To draw the squares, you simply iterate through that array.

```
$squares = array();
$total = 1024;

$squares['white'] = rand (0, 50);
$squares['lightblue'] = rand (0, 200);
$whiteblue = $squares['white'] + $squares['lightblue'];
$squares['darkblue'] = rand ($whiteblue, 750);
$squares['mediumblue'] = $total - ($squares['darkblue'] + $whiteblue);

//number of letters in white squares
$squares['whiteletters'] = rand(0, $squares['white']);
$squares['white'] -= $squares['whiteletters'];

// Create array of squares
$items = array();
foreach ($squares as $key => $count) {
    $items = array_merge($items, array_fill(0, $count, $key));
}
shuffle($items);

// Draw squares
$size = sqrt($total);
// <table>
for ($y = 0; $y < $size; $y++) {
    // <tr>
    for ($x = 0; $x < $size; $x++) {
        $square = $items[$y * $size + $x];
        // <td>
        // draw $square
        // </td>
    }
    // </tr>
}
// </table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was going to build a table and fill every cell. In your code however I don't know how to draw...

Comment: @user3290485:  I've commented the code to show where the appropriate HTML table tags would be outputted.

Comment: Thanks, it's a beauty!